# How to use SpaceDesk over a Wired Connection?

Tags: android, networking, tethering

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1" that I want to use as a second monitor with my PC. Spacedesk works great for my needs so long as I'm on a network with lots of bandwidth -- but more frequently I want to use second-monitor functionality in other environments, e.g. at a coffee shop, where the number of users bogs down network traffic and makes Spacedesk unacceptably slow.

Spacedesk doesn't natively support a wired connection, but for those who want one they suggest using USB tethering, presumably so both devices are on the same network. Problem is, my tablet is the Wifi-only version, so USB tethering isn't enabled. I rooted the device and used adb to run the commands enabling USB tethering as an option. It didn't take - the option never appeared under Settings / Connections. Then I installed ClockworkMod Tether as a 3rd party usb tether app. The PC tether software said it connected successfully to the tablet, but Spacedesk couldn't connect. Next I tried "gnirehtet", a reverse-tethering app. Got it working fine, but again Spacedesk on the tablet couldn't find the Spacedesk server on the PC.

How can I get both devices to be on the same network, without an intermediate connection (e.g. a router), in a way that preserves my PC's ability to connect to wifi, and that will allow Spacedesk to connect?

Comment: To downvoters: it's hard to express how negatively-useful your comment-less downvotes are. If I'm being stupid, missing something obvious, or violating reasonable community norms, I'd be grateful to know it. If you're willing to give feedback, please make it useful.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but unfortunately this question is off-topic on Stack Overflow because it's not about programming or app development. This could have been on-topic on either [su] (general computing hardware) or [android.se] (Android end-users), but it was already too late for this question to be migrated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out there's this thing called "Mobile Hotspot". Of course I couldn't use this on my tablet, as it had been disabled (thanks Samsung). But you can set it up on Windows easily -- in Windows 10 it's under Settings / Network & Internet / Mobile Hotspot. Connect your tablet to that hotspot and Spacedesk works like a charm.

Huge thanks to SpaceDesk customer support, who were extremely helpful in troubleshooting this apparently rather unusual situation. 5 stars both for the product, which I can now use anywhere, and the customer service.

Comment: So the only way to do this is to enable hotspot on you tablet?

Comment: Finally, something that works for me, huawei matepad t10s (non-sim version) disable both the usb tethering and mobile hotspot from the tablet. Creating the mobile hotspot from the PC solves the issue. =)

Answer (score 1):

Wifi tethering is possible with the tab A but only on android versions 6.x and below. it can be turned on via usb tethering enabling apps found in the app store that take you to the options in the settings of your device, these options appear to just be hidden in versions lower than 7 but removed in android 7 for whatever reason as the same apps just take you to an empty screen when used with 7.

If you have already upgraded to android 7.0 or above, and having spacedesk work with minimal lag is important to you, then I suggest you roll back youre tablet android version using Odin. This is what I've had to do after updating my tablet today (google it, there's plenty of guides out there)

TBH spacedesk is just poop over wifi. With USB you can watch video no problem

Comment: What is the app name?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the advice suggested here of using the mobile hotspot on my Windows 10 PC and used an old android tablet to create the extended screen to my PC using the suggested SpaceDesk app and it worked great!  The download for Spacedesk for your Windows 10 PC is at https://spacedesk.net/ and the android app is in on the Google Playstore.  Give it a try; it worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was connected to the internet over the LAN on my WIFI so I had difficulty in connecting the tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab 3) over USB. My solution to this problem is disconnect your Laptop from the WIFI router from LAN cable as well as WIFI and use the tether option in tablet and connect it to the laptop and now it will work. Now for using the inter connect your Wi-Fi or LAN cable after this.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the @Twiffy solution "Windows 10 hotspot" and worked for me. I disabled the tablet (Galaxy Tab A7) WiFi and the lag ended.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a new update, version 1.0.65, which allows **android devices** to have a direct wired connection through USB on spacedesk. Note that this function doesn't work on IOS, as well as no audio support through USB.